# How to render component again at the top level with the new props in React 0.14

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the new React.js 0.14 `setProps` method was deprecated form `React.Component`. [According to documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#new-deprecations-introduced-with-a-warning), now we should render component again with new props(using `ReactDOM.render()`)
The question is how can I do this? Let's look at an example.

AddTaskForm.js

```
import React from 'react';

class AddTaskForm extends React.Component
{
    onClick() {
        this.setProps({
            isVisible: false
        });
    }   

    render() {
        return (
            <form role="form">
                <div className="row" className={ this.props.isVisible ? 'show' : 'hidden' }>
                    <input className="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
                <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Add task</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default AddTaskForm;
```

Todo.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var AddTaskForm = require('./AddTaskForm');

class Todo extends React.Component
{
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AddTaskForm isVisible="false"></AddTaskForm>
            </div>
        );

    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Btw. I am using ES6 stage 0, if you find yourself confused with syntax

Ok, I can't call `setProps`, i had to rerender `AddTaskForm` component in `Todo.js`. How can I do this in this case? I've read this article form [react's blog](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/01/react-render-and-top-level-api.html) but wrapper don't really help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `setProps` at all. Properties in React must be immutable data, so you can't change them. Looks like `isVisible` prop is really part of component state, because depends on it component decides to show or not to show itself. The best choice for such situations when after some change of data you need to update component is state. I would recommend to read this [doc about state and what should and should not go to state](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#how-state-works)

From your example:

```
<div>
    <AddTaskForm isVisible="false"></AddTaskForm>
</div>
```

.. how do you know should `AddTaskForm` be visible? For now it's hardcoded. I suggest doing something like that:

```
render () {
    let shouldFormBeVisible = ...// somehow get to know should it be visible or not
    return (
        <div>
             shouldFormBeVisible ? <AddTaskForm /> : null
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is a big advantage: **you even don't need to render** `AddTaskForm` and if `isVisible` is false then hide it. You don't render component if it isn't needed.

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood props. So, to recap - props should be only passed from parent to children component and they should never been modified set again or updated, right?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

`isVisible` is a piece of mutable state, so it needs to be stored in state somewhere.

One way is to put it on the `AddTaskForm`:

```
import React from 'react';

class AddTaskForm extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = { isVisible: true};
    }

    onClick() {
        this.setState({
            isVisible: false
        });
    }   

    render() {
        return (
            <form role="form">
                <div className="row" className={ this.state.isVisible ? 'show' : 'hidden' }>
                    <input className="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
                <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Add task</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default AddTaskForm;
```

Todo.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var AddTaskForm = require('./AddTaskForm');

class Todo extends React.Component
{
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AddTaskForm />
            </div>
        );

    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Another way is to store it on the `Todo` component, but I think you have enough to get started.

Comment: OK, I think I get your point, maybe isVisible should be in state. But it's only example - the question is, how can I rerender AddTaskForm component to set new Props?

Comment: You pass in props from `Todo`.  You should not ever set a components own props.